# Using a Laravel's class file in non-laravel PHP

Tags: php, laravel-8

I'm trying to import classes that are in Laravel into my code (to avoid duplicating classes and code and such).

However, my non-laravel app doesn't use namespaces or composer. Whenever I try to import a class from Laravel and instantiate it, I'll get an error that the class cannot be found since Laravel's files are using a namespace. I also tried initializing the class like this:

```
include "../app/Classes/Calendar.php";
$calendar = new Calendar();
```

But alas, that still did nothing, and I am getting the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Calendar' not found in W:\xampp\htdocs\public\legacy_index.php:52 Stack trace: #0 W:\xampp\htdocs\server.php(28): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in W:\xampp\htdocs\public\legacy_index.php on line 52
```

Is there any way to do this without having to namespace the non-laravel code?
Thank you!

**Edit**:

This is my folder structure:

[image]

I'm trying to import **Calendar.php** from app/classes into **legacy_index.php** from public/

And this is my Calendar.php

```
<?php
namespace App\Classes;
use DateTime;
use DateTimeZone;
use PDO;
class Calendar
{
    private $db_connection = null;
    public $errors = array();
    public $messages = array();

    public function __construct(){}
    private function databaseConnection(){}
    private function getAppointments($startdate, $enddate){}
    public function getAppointmentsJSON($start, $end){}
}
```

Comment: By default Laravel use Autoloading. In your non-laravel app, first you have to include ```include('FileName.php')``` the class file and then you can call it.

Comment: I am including the file in my code but whenever I try to initialize the class, I get the error that the class cannot be found

Comment: you also have to use the file like: ```use Folder\SubFolder\Calendar;``` or if you have class name conflict then you can make alies of it like: ```use Folder\SubFolder\Calendar as CalendarNew;```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase I added 'use App/Classes/Calendar;' but it still didn't work. I'm certain that maybe I'm not adding it in the right way, or maybe missing some small step. I've also added my folder structure in the main post, maybe it'll help.

Comment: As you haven't shared how that class looks like, it's pretty difficult to tell where you are going wrong. Also, if your app does not use namespaces, what's the need for a `use` statement?

Comment: @NicoHaase was suggested by Anisur and I thought that maybe it *will* work that way regardless of namespace, since I haven't worked with PHP in a lot of years. I'll update the post with my class in a bit.

Comment: And what else have you tried to resolve the problem? As fas as I see, you require `../app/classes/Calendar.php`, but the folder is named `Classes` with an upper-cased C

Comment: @NicoHaase I've upper-cased the C but it still gives me that error. I've included ```include "../app/Classes/Calendar.php";``` and initialized it with ```$calendar = new Calendar();``` and it still gives me the error I added in the post

Comment: @AnisurRahman As I've mentioned while talking to Nico, adding 'use' won't do anything, and as Nico pointed out, it's because I'm not using namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by adding the namespace in the intialization of the class:

```
include "../app/Classes/Calendar.php";
$calendar = new App\Classes\Calendar();
```